# Nsight Eclipse IDE: slow CUDA program binaries

Tags: c++, performance, cuda, gpu, nsight

I am new to CUDA development and have recently switched to using Nvidia's Nsight Eclipse IDE (version 7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04).

I have a [CUDA program](https://github.com/carlren/gSLICr) that compiles and works without issue when building using cmake.

However, when I compile the program within Nsight, the resulting binary runs very slowly: >17000ms / frame (Nsight) vs <20ms / frame (cmake).

What could be causing this slowdown and how do I go about resolving this problem?

Comment: Is it perhaps compiled in debug mode?

Comment: Yes, you are right! I didn't realise that would have *such* an effect on the runtime performance. Thank you. If you write your comment as an answer, I will mark it as correct :-)